# Leetcode Next Permutation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinatorics

My solution to Leetcode [Next Permutation](https://leetcode.com/problems/next-permutation/) in Python.

> Implement next permutation, which rearranges numbers into the lexicographically next greater permutation of numbers.
>
> If such arrangement is not possible, it must rearrange it as the lowest possible order (ie, sorted in ascending order).
>
> The replacement must be in-place and use only constant extra memory.
>
> Here are some examples. Inputs are in the left-hand column and its corresponding outputs are in the right-hand column.
>
> 1,2,3 → 1,3,2
>   3,2,1 → 1,2,3
>   1,1,5 → 1,5,1

Q:if the following code is Big \$O(N)\$.

```
def nextPermutation(self, nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    def swap(i, j):
        while i < j:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    n = len(nums)
    index = n - 2
    while index > -1 and nums[index] >= nums[index + 1]:
        index -= 1
    if index == -1:
        swap(0, n - 1)
        return
    i = n - 1
    while i > index and nums[i] <= nums[index]:
        i -= 1
    nums[i], nums[index] = nums[index], nums[i]
    swap(index + 1, n - 1)
```

Comment: Please include the problem description in the question.  Off site links can go away.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a personal taste, but I don't like introducing a nested function because some code is repeated in a particular case. Maybe a refactoring 
could avoid this.

1. first you notice that index is naturally offset by one... refactor it:

   ```
   index = n - 1
   while index > 0 and nums[index-1] >= nums[index]:
       index -= 1
   if index == 0:
       swap(0, n - 1)
       return
   i = n - 1
   while i > index-1 and nums[i] <= nums[index-1]:
       i -= 1
   nums[i], nums[index-1] = nums[index-1], nums[i]
   swap(index, n - 1)
   ```
2. now you can remove the duplicated call to swap:

   ```
   if index > 0:
       i = n - 1
       while i > index-1 and nums[i] <= nums[index-1]:
           i -= 1
       nums[i], nums[index-1] = nums[index-1], nums[i]
   swap(index, n - 1)
   ```
3. and you can remove the nested function:

   ```
   n -= 1
   while index < n:
       nums[index], nums[n] = nums[n], nums[index]
       index += 1
       n -= 1
   ```

This is the resulting code. It is clear that this code is O(n) since there are no nested loops.

```
def nextPermutation(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
    """
    n = len(nums)
    index = n - 1
    while index > 0 and nums[index-1] >= nums[index]:
        index -= 1
    if index > 0:
        i = n - 1
        while i > index-1 and nums[i] <= nums[index-1]:
            i -= 1
        nums[i], nums[index-1] = nums[index-1], nums[i]
    n -= 1
    while index < n:
        nums[index], nums[n] = nums[n], nums[index]
        index += 1
        n -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> def nextPermutation(self, nums):
> ```

`self` doesn't appear to be used at all: is it necessary?

---

> ```
>     def swap(i, j):
>         while i < j:
>             nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]
>             i += 1
>             j -= 1
> ```

I find this name misleading. A swap is a single exchange. What this method does is reverse a sublist.

---

> ```
>     n = len(nums)
>     index = n - 2
> ```

`n` is standard enough as the length of a list that I find it expressive enough as a name, but what is `index` the index *of*?

> ```
>     i = n - 1
> ```

Similarly, what is `i` the index of?